# While loop comparing two variables

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I'm trying to find and print the minimum value for n that satisfies ca >= cb:

```
ap = 80000
bp = 200000
at = 1.03
bt = 1.015
n = 1
ca = ap*at*n
cb = bp*bt*n

while cb > ca:
    n = n + 1
    print(n)
```

The code just runs and prints n + 1 indefinitely, though. What is the correct approach to this problem?

Comment: Use an `if` statement

Comment: The assignments to `ca` and `cb` were one-time events.  They don't auto-update in response to later changes to `n`, which seems to be what you were expecting to happen.  You need to recalculate them each time through the loop

Comment: Put the actual question you had in hand. Your logic is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ap = 80000
bp = 200000
at = 1.03
bt = 1.015
n = 1
ca = ap*at*n
cb = bp*bt*n

while cb > ca:
  n += 1
  ca = ap*at*n
  cb = bp*bt*n
```

This won't converge though.

Comment: this doesn't converge: as long as `bp*bt` is greater than `ap*at`, the change of `n` won't change the truth of `cb > ca`

Comment: this code may come to an end if you use finite data types, like in c, but not in python

Comment: Correct @Aemyl I was just editing my answer for that :)

Comment: thanks ketan! your answer and a little change in my logic solved my problem